# Single Table Inheritance with a legacy schema and composite keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, single-table-inheritance

I'm trying to set up single table inheritance with a legacy schema but am having a hard time. Here is the schema for the table, bms_codes, being inherited from:

```
create_table "bms_codes", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
  t.decimal  "code_id",                               :null => false
  t.string   "code_group",             :limit => 35,  :null => false
  t.string   "code_name_short",        :limit => 100
  ...
end
```

Here is code.rb. I've set up column aliases so there is a type column to inherit from.

```
class Code < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name :bms_codes
  set_primary_keys :code_id, :code_group #composite keys using the composite_primary_keys gem

  alias_attribute :id, :code_id
  alias_attribute :type, :code_group
  alias_attribute :description, :code_name_short
end
```

It is my understanding that inquiry_tracking_role.rb should pull in all records from Code that have a type of 'Inquiry Tracking Role'. Is this correct? In console if I type InquiryTrackingRole.all I get the same results as Code.all.

```
class InquiryTrackingRole < Code
end
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible or is our schema too fubar'ed?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord makes the assumption that the database belongs to the application, and that the database will follow ActiveRecord conventions and assumptions. It is not designed to map any schema to any domain model.

If you want to map your schema to your domain model, you might give DataMapper a try.